# Suggestions for getting PHP to act as an AMF client

Tags: php, client, amf

I have been looking at Zend AMF and AMFPHP to see if either can operate as a client and I am not finding anything that says it definitely can or cannot operate as a client.

Is this possible withe either of these libraries? Are there other solid AMF libraries for PHP that will provide a client interface?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using SabreAMF from [this site](http://osflash.org/sabreamf), but this is not a checked way.